# Imputing missing observations when total value of missing observations is given

Tags: regression, panel-data, missing-data, data-imputation

I have a panel dataset with country-time. Below is an example:

```
country year  var1
USA     1991   10
UK      1991    5
Canada  1991    .
China   1991    .
India   1991    3
Mexico  1991    .
Other   1991   30
```

"Other" given in the country is the sum of all `var1` for the countries with missing observations for that given year (that is, 30 is somehow distributed among Canada, China and Mexico in the given example). I'd like to run some regression with var1 as an exogenous variable, along with other variables not listed above. However, when I run regression, I'm unsure if imputing those missing variables as 0 is the best way to go about regression since we have the information of the total value given in the "Other".

To make the question more concrete, I'd like to know:

Given the unknown distribution of `var1` among the missing countries, does the regression with missing values imputed as 0 give coefficient closer to the 'true' coefficient, than say, regression with missing values imputed as the average of the total `var1`, ie. assuming uniform distribution?

Or is there a better way of imputing those missing observations other than imputing 0 or average value?

Some extra information about the dataset:

In some years, the value given in the "Others" could go up to as high as 50% of the total value of `var1`, while in many other years it's as low as 2-5%.

In addition, it is hard to simply interpolate the values from the previous year and the year after, since if the data is missing for one year, the data for that country is mostly missing for all years.

The reason for missingness is because the data source (government) only reports the top countries with highest value of `var1` over years, and sums the rest as 'Others'. In some years, the list of countries change, but the number of countries that they report remains about 20. We'd like to use the data for all countries in our dataset (about 150 countries, but we only have data for roughly 20 countries + Other).

Comment: What is the pattern of missingness? (You give some indication at the very end.) Indeed, what are the reasons for missingness?

Comment: Edited to include the reason for missingness.